# Weighted ridge regression in R

Tags: r, regression, ridge-regression, weighted-regression, irls

How can we do weighted ridge regression in R?

In MASS package in R, I can do weighted linear regression by passing a weight parameter to `lm`. It can be seen that the model with weights is different from the one without weights.

```
# with weights
> model = lm( y ~ X - 1, weights = w)
> model$coeff
X(Intercept) XSepal.Length  XSepal.Width XPetal.Length  XPetal.Width
-2.1135159    -0.1890203     1.8198141    -1.1771699     2.2840825 

# without weights
> model = lm( y ~ X - 1)
> model$coeff
X(Intercept) XSepal.Length  XSepal.Width XPetal.Length  XPetal.Width 
-5.23869771    0.09802533    2.16742901   -1.07331102    2.40425352
```

However, when I try to replicate the same with `lm.ridge`, model generated with and without weights are same.

```
  # with weights
  > model = lm.ridge(y ~ X - 1, lambda=lmd, weights = w)
  > model
  X(Intercept) XSepal.Length  XSepal.Width XPetal.Length  XPetal.Width 
  -5.17253104    0.08770593    2.15946954   -1.06284572    2.38714738

  # without weights
  > model = lm.ridge(y ~ X - 1, lambda=lmd, weights = w)
  > model
  X(Intercept) XSepal.Length  XSepal.Width XPetal.Length  XPetal.Width 
  -5.17253104    0.08770593    2.15946954   -1.06284572    2.38714738
```

Edit 1: 
In linear model, I can calculate stderr of coefficients as follows:

```
rss = sum( residuals( model, type="pearson")^2 )
dispersion = rss / model$df.residual
stderr = sqrt( diag(vcov(model)) ) / sqrt(dispersion)
```

Comment: You could use the `glmnet` function from the package of the same name, with argument `alpha` = 0.

Comment: Thanks. That does the weighted ridge regression, but I have to calcukate the stderr too. How can I get or calculate stderr in the coefficients returned by glmnet? In linear model, I could do this using code given in `Edit 1`, but this does not work in case of glmnet.

Comment: I don't know of any way to get standard errors of the coefficient estimates from glmnet. The answer at the following link explains why standard errors may not be useful in this situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937331/how-to-get-statistical-summary-information-from-glmnet-model

Comment: @mark999 You should post your comments as an answer.

Comment: @Kodiologist Thanks for your comment, but I'll just leave them as comments.